# Как выбрать последнюю строку из базы данных?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Вот есть 2 строки из базы данных. Мне нужно выбрать последнюю из них (использую python 3.7.6, Windows 10). Как мне правильно исправить мой SQL-запрос? То есть должно быть что-то вроде: - Выбрать последнюю строку из двух найденных одинаковых
(нужно опираться не на id, а на последнюю строку из найденного результата!)
`SELECT 'Где-то здесь должно быть условие, по которому выберется последняя строка'adress FROM orders WHERE user_id ='245' LIMIT 1'`

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/how-do-i-select-an-entire-row-which-has-the-largest-id-in-the-table

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, там конкретно говорится об уникальном идентификаторе. А если, предположим у меня  не было столбца id. Как выйти из данного положения?)
(Знаю, что в реальных БД всгеда есть инкрементация)

Comment: добавить его в таблицу и, тем самым, не придумывать себе лишних проблем)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, Может вы и правы:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вам нужа последяя среди строк, у которых `user_id=245`.

```
SELECT adress 
    FROM orders 
    WHERE user_id ='245'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Для удобстав разделил на строки, можно написать в одну, проблем не будет

Comment: Вы вопрос прочитали?

Comment: @Xander, если id - автоинремент, то чем дальше, тем id больше. Да, простите, не заметил такого странного условия, сейчас обдумаю...

Comment: @Xander впрочем я прислушался к Вашему ответу насчёт порядка. Всё-таки, как сказал Alexander Chernin - добавить лучше инкрементацию и не делать себе проблем.

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, можно сказать, что я искал что-то подобное, в моём случае это тоже сработало)

Answer (score 2):

В стандарте SQL нет такой штуки, как порядок строк в таблице. То есть, в возвращаемом запросе никакая из строк не является "первой" или "последней", если вы явно не задали порядок сортировки с помощью ORDER BY.